# Pyspark runtime error when i try to print rdd

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I get this error when trying to print the contents of a RDD:

> "RuntimeError: SparkContext or SparkSession should be created first."

I have created a spark session as well so I am unsure as to why I get this error.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType


# Define the function to capitalize words in the title
def cap_title(words):
    x = words.split('.')
    capitalized_words = [x.capitalize() for word in words]
    return ' '.join(capitalized_words)

# Convert the Python function into a UDF
capitalize_udf = udf(cap_title, StringType())

# Apply the UDF to the RDD
transformed_rdd = c_rdd.map(lambda x: [x[0], capitalize_udf(x[1])])
print(transformed_rdd.take(5))
```

The `transformed_rdd` is created as intended, but I get the error only when trying to print the RDD, i.e. the last line of code.

Answer (score 0):

To run anything with Spark, you must first initiate a `SparkContext`. This needs to happen even if you are running in standalone/local mode without a cluster.

If you notice in your code, `c_rdd` is not defined. Ideally, this should come as a result of initiating your `SparkContext`. You obtain RDDs by reading data (or parallelizing variables) using the created `SparkContext`.

From Spark docs

> The first thing a Spark program must do is to create a SparkContext
> object, which tells Spark how to access a cluster. To create a
> `SparkContext` you first need to build a `SparkConf` object that contains
> information about your application.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("YourAppName").setMaster(master)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

With this, in relation to you code, you can potentially call `parallelize()` on a variable in your code to obtain your initial RDD, you called it `c_rdd`. Then you can apply transformations on this RDD.

```
my_list = [ "First Word", "Second Word", "Not the last word", "Last Word" ]
c_rdd = sc.parallelize(my_list)
transformed_rdd = c_rdd.map(lambda x: [x[0], capitalize_udf(x[1])])
print(transformed_rdd.take(5))
```

The Spark docs provide a very handy guide for this:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#initializing-spark

Of course there are more ways of creating RDDs (e.g. reading directly from disk, cloud, databases etc.) which are used more often then parallelize in real world applications.

That said, you will need to run this code from a Spark environment, you cannot just submit this from any python environment. If you don't think you have an environment setup, most likely you want to run this by installing Spark client on your local system and then running it in a terminal using something like:

```
./bin/pyspark --master local[4]
```

Or follow any tutorials to setup your favorite editor/notebook environment to run with Spark. Just remember that only importing the libraries is not enough.